# How to select the first element of a column of type array column using knex.select()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, knex.js

We are able to select the first element of a column of type array in Postgres SQL database. But I'm not able to query the same using knex.

I have tried this.

```
database('items')
    .select({icon: 'images[0]})
    .then(data => {
    res.send(data) 
}
```

Expecting the first element of images column of items table.

Comment: Is `icon` column is of a type json?

Comment: An icon is not the column Images is a column of type text[] @felixmosh

Comment: How it will look like in regular SQL string, without Knex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `first()` function. It returns the first row in your table (in whatever order the table is sorted).  The `.select('images')` will limit the columns returned to just `images`.

```
knex
  .select('images')
  .table('items')
  .first()
  .then((data) => {
    // first row of 'images' is an array.
    // return only the first item in array.
    res.send(data[0]);
})
```

Comment: The promise above returns row of images column. I want the first item of the first row of images column. @user45392

Comment: @PratapSharma in that case, try `res.send(data[0]);`.  See my edit above.

Comment: What if there is no row satisfying query?

Comment: @Noname it should still work, just returning an empty result.  In this case, since the expected result was an array, the indexing `data[0]` may give an error though

Answer (score 0):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-ACCESSING

This seems to build correct kind of query for it in knex (notice that in postgresql arrays starts from index 1):

```
knex('items').select({icon: knex.raw('??[1]', ['images'])})
```

Here is runkit example of generated query https://runkit.com/embed/1apx76bh4u40